# Swift Metal Shader Issue

Tags: swift, opengl, shader, metal

I have been trying for hours to make the following shader written in opengl work in metal swift:
https://github.com/gl-transitions/gl-transitions/blob/master/transitions/SimpleZoom.glsl
I am using kernel method in shader function, following is the one output frame of resulting video.
[Image frame during zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNGuo.jpg)

I have written some other shaders too that work successfully, but stuck on this one for 5+ hours.

Current Code:

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;
float2 zoom(float2 uv, float amount)

{
    return 0.5f + ((uv - 0.5f) * (1.0f - amount));
}

float4 getColor(texture2d<float, access::sample> tex2d, float2 uv)

{
    constexpr sampler sampler2d(coord::normalized,

                                address::clamp_to_edge,

                                filter::linear,

                                mip_filter::linear

                                );

    return tex2d.sample(sampler2d, float2(uv.x, 1.0f - uv.y));
}

float4 transition(texture2d<float, access::sample> fromTexture,
                  texture2d<float, access::sample> toTexture,
                  float nQuick,
                  float progress,
                  float2 uv
                  )
{

    uv.x /= fromTexture.get_width();
    uv.y /= fromTexture.get_height();
    uv.y = 1.0f - uv.y;

    float4 fromColor = getColor(fromTexture, zoom(uv, smoothstep(0.0f, nQuick, progress)));
    float4 toColor = getColor(toTexture, uv);

    return mix (fromColor, toColor, smoothstep(nQuick-0.2f, 1.0f, progress));
}



kernel void transition_simplezoom(texture2d<float, access::sample> inTexture [[ texture(0) ]],

                            texture2d<float, access::sample> inTexture2 [[ texture(1) ]],

                            texture2d<float, access::write> outTexture [[ texture(2) ]],

                            device const float *progress [[ buffer(1) ]],

                            device float *result [[buffer(0)]],

                            device const float *zoom_quickness [[buffer(2)]],

                            uint2 gid [[ thread_position_in_grid ]])
{
    float zoomQuickness = *zoom_quickness;

    float prog = *progress;

    prog = 1.0 - prog;

    float2 ngid = float2(gid);``

    float nQuick = clamp(zoomQuickness, 0.2, 1.0);

    return outTexture.write(transition(inTexture, inTexture2, nQuick, prog, float2(ngid)),

                            gid);
}
```

Dispatching Threadgroups:

```
guard let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer(), let computeCommandEncoder = commandBuffer.makeComputeCommandEncoder() else {
            return nil
        }

        // Set the compute pipeline state for the command encoder.
        computeCommandEncoder.setComputePipelineState(computePipelineState)

        // Set the input and output textures for the compute shader.
        computeCommandEncoder.setTexture(inputTexture, index: 0)
        computeCommandEncoder.setTexture(inputTexture1, index: 1)
        computeCommandEncoder.setTexture(inputTexture2, index: 2)
let threadGroupCount = MTLSizeMake(1, 1, 1)

        let threadGroups: MTLSize = {
            MTLSizeMake(Int(1280) / threadGroupCount.width, Int(720) / threadGroupCount.height, 1)
        }()
computeCommandEncoder.dispatchThreadgroups(threadGroups, threadsPerThreadgroup: threadGroupCount)
```

Expected output: https://gl-transitions.com/editor/SimpleZoom

[Current result with the code above](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BZstjVlxMmY&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: In the future, consider posting relevant portions of your code so that others can point out specific issues. Also, it's not immediately obvious from your question what the expected output is, so including an example of what you expect to see when things are working correctly is very helpful.

Comment: @warrenm I have updated my question. Please have a look.

Comment: Can you share the Swift code you're using for dispatching the compute work (i.e. your threadgroup size and count calculations)? Is it the case that the height of the grid actually matches the height of the "from" video frame?

Comment: @warrenm Added the code, and my both videos are of dimension 1280,720.

Comment: @warrenm the zooming effect works fine when i swap the texture variables in shader, like in starting, output texture is texture1 and during transition it goes from texture2 to texture1 with zooming effect correctly and then back to texture2. It messes up too if i do the transition from texture2 to texture1 without swapping variable in shader.

Comment: To be clear, are there three distinct textures in play, or do you bind the same texture as the output and one of the inputs?

Comment: @warrenm There are two distinct textures(inputTexture, inputTexture1), third one is for output(inputTexture2). I make the third texture from pixelBuffer1 before sending in to the shader.

Answer (score 2):

In converting this shader, I tried to keep as close to the spirit and structure of the original as possible. But, since there are significant differences between GLSL and MSL, I did have to take some liberties:

- Assume that uniforms and other globals would arrive in the form of `constant` buffers
- Pass parameters from the fragment shader down to utility functions rather than accessing them as globals

With that said, here's my best attempt at a Metal shader that performs your desired zoom effect:

```
struct VertexIn {
    float2 position  [[attribute(0)]];
    float2 texCoords [[attribute(1)]];
};

struct VertexOut {
    float4 position [[position]];
    float2 texCoords;
};

float4 getColor(texture2d<float, access::sample> tex2d, float2 uv) {
    constexpr sampler sampler2d(coord::normalized,
                                address::clamp_to_edge,
                                filter::linear,
                                mip_filter::linear);

    return tex2d.sample(sampler2d, float2(uv.x, 1.0f - uv.y));
}

float2 zoom(float2 uv, float amount) {
    return 0.5f + ((uv - 0.5f) * (1.0f - amount));
}

float4 transition (texture2d<float, access::sample> fromTexture,
                   texture2d<float, access::sample> toTexture,
                   float nQuick,
                   float progress,
                   float2 uv)
{
    float4 fromColor = getColor(fromTexture, zoom(uv, smoothstep(0.0f, nQuick, progress)));
    float4 toColor = getColor(toTexture, uv);
    return mix(fromColor, toColor, smoothstep(nQuick - 0.2f, 1.0f, progress));
}

vertex VertexOut textured_vertex(VertexIn in [[stage_in]]) {
    VertexOut out;
    out.position = float4(in.position, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    out.texCoords = in.texCoords;
    return out;
}

fragment float4 zoomed_textured_fragment(VertexOut in [[stage_in]],
                                         constant float& zoom_quickness [[buffer(0)]],
                                         constant float& progress       [[buffer(1)]],
                                         texture2d<float, access::sample> fromTexture [[texture(0)]],
                                         texture2d<float, access::sample> toTexture   [[texture(1)]])
{
    float nQuick = clamp(zoom_quickness, 0.2 , 1.0);
    return transition(fromTexture, toTexture, nQuick, progress, in.texCoords);
}
```

You seem to already have rendering code, so I'll just note that I pass in the parameters as individual constant buffers using the following Swift code:

```
var zoomSpeed: Float = 0.5
renderCommandEncoder.setFragmentBytes(&zoomSpeed, length: MemoryLayout<Float>.size, index: 0)

renderCommandEncoder.setFragmentBytes(&progress, length: MemoryLayout<Float>.size, index: 1)
```

where `progress` is a `Float` var that changes over time to perform the zoom animation.

Comment: sorry for not posting code before, i have rewritten your code in my kernel mthod, but the results are the same as before.